# For all $n>2$, $\mu(1!)+\mu(2!)+\cdots+\mu(n!)=1$

Tags: number-theory

Show that for all $n>2$, $$\mu(1!)+\mu(2!)+\cdots+\mu(n!)=1$$ Here $\mu$ is the Mobius function.

Comment: For anyone who knows anything about $\mu(n)$, this is a ridiculously easy question, as JimmyK4542's answer shows.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: For $n \ge 4$, we have that $2^2 = 4$ divides $n!$. What does this tell you about $\mu(n!)$ for $n \ge 4$?

After answering the above question, you only need to compute $\mu(1!)$, $\mu(2!)$, and $\mu(3!)$.